# Why does mod_rewrite slow down my web site significantly?

Tags: performance, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a website `mywrapper.com` that does nothing but redirect to a specific page in another domain, `http://www.example.com/coming-soon.html` using mod_rewrite. However, the redirects are **incredibly** slow. The first redirection from (say) `mywrapper.com/foo` takes 5-10 seconds or more. Subsequent redirects from `mywrapper.com/foo` are immediate. (This behavior happens for any page, not just `foo`.) Any ideas why?

My apache config (`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mywrapper.com.conf`) is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@mywrapper.com
  ServerName  www.mywrapper.com
  ServerAlias mywrapper.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywrapper\.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywrapper\.com$
  RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/coming-soon.html" [R=301,L]

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/html/mywrapper.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/html/mywrapper.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Hitting `http://www.example.com/coming-soon.html` directly is instantaneous.

The webserver (same machine hosts both domains) has 2GB RAM and is not swapping, so free memory doesn't seem to be the issue. It runs a fairly vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 LTS setup. There are no errors in the Apache logs.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: you're doing a 301 client-side redirect, which forces a full-blown roundtrip to the client and a new http request. going to `example.com` DOESN'T trigger your rewrites. so... start debugging. figure out what's slow. maybe the rewrite is instantaneous, but your DNS is hosed and it takes the client 5 seconds to resolve `mywrapper.com`.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer. According to an HTTP trace, my browser isn't even sending the http GET to "mywrapper.com/foo" for those first 5-10 seconds, but only the first time. If I then try to hit a different URL "mywrapper.com/bar", I get the 5-10 second delay again. On the other hand, if I "ping" mywrapper.com, the response is always immediate, so can the issue be DNS?

Comment: PS: The actual domain is "heam.info", in case you can see anything obviously wrong with it.

Comment: you could try eliminating mod_rewrite entirely, since you're doing a plain simple redirect anyways. `<vhost> RedirectPermanent / http://example.com</vhost>`-type stuff. then at least you'll have a clue if it's a rewrite issue or something else.

Comment: Thanks. Your `RedirectPermanent` line causes an instantaneous redirect. However, `RedirectMatch "/(.*)" "http://example.com"` produces the long delay.

Comment: Oops, never mind. Both RedirectPermanent and RedirectMatch have the long delay.

Comment: It looks like the problem is localized to the Windows 7 client PC I was testing on, but I still can't explain it. If I hit mywrapper.com from the latest Chrome, Firefox, or IE11, the slowness occurs. However, if I use Cygwin "wget" on the *same* client PC, the slowness goes away. Additionally, I cannot reproduce the slowness on any other client PC. Why would "wget" have different network behavior than the three major browsers?